# Number displaying as double in editablegrid-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have downloaded editablegrid-mysql from https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid-mysql-example, There is a little issue with the grid that it displays number as double, For example when the id is 1000 it displays the value as 1.000, though the datatype is integer. I have checked the code but unable to find the correct one.

PHP CODE

```
$grid->addColumn('id', 'id', 'integer', NULL, false);
$grid->addColumn('first_name', 'First Name', 'string');  
$grid->addColumn('last_name', 'Last_name', 'string');  
$grid->addColumn('bridge_id', 'Bridge ID', 'integer');
```

Comment: Could be worth asking the developer(s) here: https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid-mysql-example/issues

Comment: Are you sure 1.000 is a double? `.` is in some locale used as thousand separator

Comment: Probably better as an issue on the github repo; I would imagine this is too specific for SO.

Comment: Ok let me see, asking the developers